# How to use spark Java API to read binary file stream from HDFS?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, streaming

I am writing a component which needs to get the new binary file in a specific HDFS path, so that I can do some online learning based on this data. So, I want to read binary file created by Flume from HDFS in stream. I found several functions provided by spark API, such as

```
public JavaDStream<byte[]> binaryRecordsStream(String directory,int recordLength)
```

and

```
public <K,V,F extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat<K,V>> 
     JavaPairInputDStream<K,V> fileStream(String directory, Class<K> kClass, Class<V> vClass, Class<F> fClass)
```

But, I really do not know how to use these functions. I have tried `binaryRecordStream`, but it defines the specific length of file, so it is not good.

For `fileStream` function, I have used:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new   SparkConf().setAppName("SparkFileStreamTest").setMaster("local[2]");

// Create the context with the specified batch size
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(durationInMillis));

JavaPairInputDStream<LongWritable, BytesWritable> inputDStream = jssc.fileStream(hdfsPath, LongWritable.class, BytesWritable.class, CustomInputFormat.class);

//**********************************************************************
JavaPairInputDStream<LongWritable, BytesWritable> inputDStream = jssc.fileStream(
            hdfsPath, LongWritable.class, BytesWritable.class, CustomInputFormat.class);

JavaDStream<byte[]> content = inputDStream.map(new Function<Tuple2<LongWritable, BytesWritable>, byte[]>() {
    @Override
    public byte[] call(Tuple2<LongWritable, BytesWritable> tuple2) {
        System.out.println("----------------[testReadFileStreamFromHDFS] ENTER ......");
        if (tuple2 == null) {
            System.out.println("----------------[testReadFileStreamFromHDFS] TUPLE = NULL");
            System.out.println("----------------[testReadFileStreamFromHDFS] END.");
            return null;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("----------------[testReadFileStreamFromHDFS] KEY = [" + tuple2._1().toString() + "]");
            System.out.println("----------------[testReadFileStreamFromHDFS] VAL-LENGTH = [" + tuple2._2().getBytes().length + "]");
            System.out.println("----------------[testReadFileStreamFromHDFS] END.");
            return tuple2._2().getBytes();
        }
    }
});

/***********************************************************************/
if (content == null) {
        System.out.println("----------------[testReadFileStreamFromHDFS] CONTENT = NULL");
}
else {
    System.out.println("----------------[testReadFileStreamFromHDFS] CONTENT-length = [" + content.count());
    content.print();
}

System.out.println("----------------[testReadFileStreamFromHDFS] END-111.");

jssc.start();
jssc.awaitTermination();
System.out.println("----------------[testReadFileStreamFromHDFS] END-222.");
```

For `CustomInputFormat`, I created

```
public class CustomInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<LongWritable, BytesWritable> {

private CustomInputSplit mInputSplit;

public CustomInputFormat() {
    mInputSplit = new CustomInputSplit();
}

@Override
public List<InputSplit> getSplits(JobContext context)
        throws IOException {

    System.out.println("----------------[CustomInputFormat] 1111 ......");
    final ArrayList<InputSplit> result = new ArrayList<InputSplit>();
    result.add(mInputSplit);

    System.out.println("----------------[CustomInputFormat] 2222 ......");
    return result;
}

@Override
public RecordReader<LongWritable, BytesWritable> createRecordReader(
        InputSplit inputSplit, TaskAttemptContext taskAttemptContext)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    System.out.println("----------------[CustomInputFormat] 3333 ......");
    System.out.println("----------------[CustomInputFormat] ENTER createRecordReader, inputSplit-length = ["
            + inputSplit.getLength() + "]");

    mInputSplit.init(inputSplit);

    System.out.println("----------------[CustomInputFormat] 4444 ......");
    return new CustomRecordReader();
}

@Override
protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path filename) {
    System.out.println("----------------[CustomInputFormat] 5555 ......");
    return false;
}

public class CustomRecordReader extends RecordReader<LongWritable, BytesWritable> {

private BytesWritable mValues;
private int mCursor;

public CustomRecordReader() {
    System.out.println("----------------[CustomRecordReader] 1111 ......");
    mValues = null;
    mCursor = 0;
    System.out.println("----------------[CustomRecordReader] 2222 ......");
}

@Override
public void initialize(InputSplit inputSplit, TaskAttemptContext taskAttemptContext)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("----------------[CustomRecordReader] 3333 ......");
    CustomInputSplit customInputSplit = (CustomInputSplit) inputSplit;
    mValues = customInputSplit.getValues();
    System.out.println("----------------[CustomRecordReader] 4444 ......");
}

@Override
public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("----------------[CustomRecordReader] 5555 ......");
    boolean existNext = (mCursor == 0);
    mCursor++;
    System.out.println("----------------[CustomRecordReader] 6666 ......");
    return existNext;
}

@Override
public LongWritable getCurrentKey() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("----------------[CustomRecordReader] 7777 ......");
    return new LongWritable(0);
}

@Override
public BytesWritable getCurrentValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("----------------[CustomRecordReader] 8888 ......");
    return mValues;
}

@Override
public float getProgress() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("----------------[CustomRecordReader] 9999 ......");
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("----------------[CustomRecordReader] AAAA ......");
    mValues = null;
}
}

public class CustomInputSplit extends InputSplit implements Writable {

private long mLength;
private String[] mLocations;

private final BytesWritable mContent;

public CustomInputSplit() {
    System.out.println("----------------[CustomInputSplit] 1111 ......");
    mLength = 0;
    mLocations = null;

    mContent = new BytesWritable();
    System.out.println("----------------[CustomInputSplit] 2222 ......");
}

public void init(InputSplit inputSplit) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("----------------[CustomInputSplit] 3333 ......");
    mLength = inputSplit.getLength();

    String[] locations = inputSplit.getLocations();
    if (locations != null) {
        int numLocations = locations.length;
        mLocations = new String[numLocations];
        for (int i = 0; i < numLocations; i++) {
            mLocations[i] = locations[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("----------------[CustomInputSplit] 4444 ......");
}

@Override
public long getLength() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("----------------[CustomInputSplit] 5555 ......");
    return mLength;
}

@Override
public String[] getLocations() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    if (mLocations == null) {
        System.out.println("----------------[CustomInputSplit] 6666-0001 ...... mLocations = [NULL]");
        mLocations = new String[] {"localhost"};
    }
    System.out.println("----------------[CustomInputSplit] 6666-0002 ...... mLocations-length = [" + mLocations.length + "]");
    return mLocations;
}

@Override
public void write(DataOutput dataOutput) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("----------------[CustomInputSplit] 7777 ......");
    mContent.write(dataOutput);
}

@Override
public void readFields(DataInput dataInput) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("----------------[CustomInputSplit] 8888 ......");
    mContent.readFields(dataInput);
}

public BytesWritable getValues() {
    System.out.println("----------------[CustomInputSplit] 9999 ......");
    return mContent;
}
}
```

But when I print:

`System.out.println("----------------[testReadFileStreamFromHDFS] VAL-LENGTH = [" + tuple2._2().getBytes().length + "]");`

I always get 0 length:

`----------------[testReadFileStreamFromHDFS] VAL-LENGTH = [0]`

Are there some problems with `CustomerInputFormat.class`? Does anybody know how to use Spark stream Java API to read binary file from HDFS?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     JavaStreamingContext context
     JavaSparkContext jContext = context.sparkContext();
     JavaPairRDD<String, PortableDataStream> rdd = jContext.binaryFiles(fsURI + directoryPath);

     JavaRDD<Object> rdd1 = rdd.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, PortableDataStream>, Object>() {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = -7894402430221488712L;

     @Override
     public Object call(Tuple2<String, PortableDataStream> arg0) throws Exception {
     byte[] imageInByte = arg0._2().toArray();
     String base64Encoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageInByte);
     return (arg0._1 + Constants.COMMA_DELIMITER + base64Encoded).getBytes();
     }
     });
     java.util.Queue<JavaRDD<Object>> queue = new LinkedList();
     queue.add(rdd1);
     JavaDStream<Object> dStream = context.queueStream(queue);
```

The only limitation with this apparoach is that it will not be able to read new files from HDFS created after starting this pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Approach:
Write a Custom Receiver:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.input.PortableDataStream;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaReceiverInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.Receiver;
class DFSReceiver extends Receiver<byte[]> {

    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1051061769769056605L;
    Long windowSize = 20000l;

    /** Instantiates a new RMQ receiver. */
    DFSReceiver() {
        super(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        System.out.println("Inside onStart method");
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    receive();
                } 
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    LOGGER.error("Exception raised at DFSReceiverHelper , exception : " + e);
                }

            }
        }.start();
    }

    /** Receive.
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     *             the exception */
    protected void receive() throws Exception {
        try {
            ConnectionMetadata connectionMetadata = ConnectionMetadataFactory.getConnectionMetadataObj(ConnectionConstants.HDFS_DATA_STORE);
            String connectionId = connectionMetadata.getConnectionId(ConnectionConstants.HDFS_DATA_STORE, connectionName);
            ConnectionMetaDataDTO c = connectionMetadata.getConnectionMetaDataById(connectionId);

            Map<String, Object> map = connectionMetadata.getConnectionConfigParameters(c);
            FileSystem fs = HDFSUtils.getFileSystemInstance(map);

            JavaPairRDD<String, PortableDataStream> rdd = sparkContext.binaryFiles(fsURI + directoryPath);
            List<Tuple2<String, PortableDataStream>> rddList = rdd.collect();
            for (Tuple2<String, PortableDataStream> arg0 : rddList) {
                byte[] imageInByte = arg0._2().toArray();
                String base64Encoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageInByte);
                store((arg0._1 + Constants.COMMA_DELIMITER + base64Encoded).getBytes());
            }

            Long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println();
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(windowSize);
            while (true) {
                List<Path> newFiles = checkIfNewFileCreated(fs, new Path(fsURI + directoryPath), time);
                for (Path p : newFiles) {
                    JavaPairRDD<String, PortableDataStream> rdd11 = sparkContext.binaryFiles(p.toString());
                    Tuple2<String, PortableDataStream> arg0 = rdd11.first();
                    byte[] imageInByte = arg0._2().toArray();
                    String base64Encoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageInByte);
                    store((arg0._1 + Constants.COMMA_DELIMITER + base64Encoded).getBytes());
                }
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(windowSize);
                time += windowSize;
            }
        } catch (ShutdownSignalException s) {
            LOGGER.error("ShutdownSignalException raised in receive method of DFSReceiver", s);
        }
    }

    private List<Path> checkIfNewFileCreated(FileSystem fs, Path p, Long timeStamp) throws IOException {
        List<Path> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (fs.isDirectory(p)) {
            FileStatus[] fStatus = fs.listStatus(p);
            for (FileStatus status : fStatus) {
                if (status.isFile() && timeStamp < status.getModificationTime() && timeStamp + windowSize >= status.getModificationTime()) {
                    fileList.add(status.getPath());
                }
            }
        }
        return fileList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {

    }
}
```

With this receiver you will be able to read newly created files also every 20 second.